# Do I need to submit a 1024*1024 iTunesArtwork for my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, hid

According to new iOS HID, there is a requirement for 1024 * 1024 app icon

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1

Will I need to include it and how should I name the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**YES**

Seems like they have enforced it now. 512s are no longer approved.

The new text reads :

> "The large app icon you uploaded is not valid. It must be a .jpeg,
>   .jpg, .tif, .tiff, or .png file that is 1024 x 1024 pixels, at least
>   72 DPI, and in the RGB color space."

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's required. The document also states that it's for the App Store, so I think it will be part of the process of app submission to iTunes connect, rather than being a part of your app bundle proper.

Do you have a developer account? You can log into iTunes connect, go to "Manage your Apps", and take a look under "Add new app", which appears in the upper left corner.

Comment: It says "or" in iTunes connect: A large version of your app icon that will be used on the App Store. It must be at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and 512 x 512 or 1024 x 1024 pixels (it cannot be scaled up). The file type must be .jpeg, .jpg, .tif, .tiff, or .png. It must be flat artwork without rounded corners.